# How java 8 evaluates internally when passing "pass a reference" to a method that matches the parameter list of abstract method?

Tags: java-8, functional-interface

I have been working with java 8 functional interfaces and I noticed something unusual when I started executing below code.

```
interface Carnivore{

  default int calories( List<String> food)
  {
     System.out.println("=======line ABC ");
     return food.size() * 100;
  }

   int eat(List<String> foods);

}

class Tiger implements Carnivore{

   public int eat(List<String> foods)
   {
     System.out.println("eating  "+ foods);

     return foods.size();
   }
}   


public class TestClass {

  public static int size(List<String> names){
     System.out.println("======line XYZ ");
     return names.size()*2;
  }
  public static void process(List<String> names, Carnivore c){
     c.eat(names);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> fnames =   Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

    Tiger t = new Tiger();

    process(fnames, t::eat);
    process(fnames, t::calories);
    process(fnames, TestClass::size ); // ----> this is where I am confused.  
  }
}
```

As you can see that static method `process(List<String> names, Carnivore c)` takes object type `Carnivore`. The method call `process(fnames, TestClass::size )` works, and there's no compile time error, how is this possible? I'm not able to comprehend how internally this method call works. I was expecting an error because `TestClass` is not `Carnivore`.

The best answer I found: *"You can either pass a `Carnivore` instance explicitly or pass a reference to a method that matches the parameter list of Carnivore's abstract method `eat(List<String> foods)`"*

The part `pass a reference to a method that matches the parameter list of abstract method` is confusing to me.

Appreciated if experts help me understand what happens when `process(fnames, TestClass::size );` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Carnivore` is a functional interface having a single abstract method `int eat(List<String> foods);`.

Therefore, any method that fits the signature of the `eat` method can be used to implement the interface.

`public static int size(List<String> names)` is such a method, since it takes a `List<String>` argument and returns an `int`. Therefore `TestClass::size` can be passed as an argument of type `Carnivore`, which is why `process(fnames, TestClass::size);` passes compilation.

BTW, `Tiger` does not have to implement the `Carnivore` interface for `process(fnames, t::eat);` to pass compilation, since the `public int eat(List<String> foods)` method also matches the signature of the functional interface's single abstract method.

Comment: `process(fnames, t::calories)` will not compile if I don't implement `Carnivore`. Anyways, I have tested my code to see what happens with implement and without implements. And I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @MKod `process(fnames, t::calories)` will not compile if your `Tiger` class doesn't implement `Carnivore` since the `calories` method is only defined in the interface, so `Tiger` class doesn't have that method if it doesn't implement the interface.